# Android: Quickblox localview placed below opponent view after onRemoteVideoTrackReceive

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I use Quickblox for video calls

Everything is good, but after onRemoteVideoTrackReceive, localview placed below opponentview. as a result, user not view itself video and only view opponent view

My code :

```
@Override
    public void onLocalVideoTrackReceive(BaseSession baseSession, QBRTCVideoTrack qbrtcVideoTrack) {
        Log.i("errorCheck","inVideo 999");
        localVideoTrack = qbrtcVideoTrack;

        mediaStreamManager = baseSession.getMediaStreamManager();
        qbrtcVideoTrack.addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(localView));
    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoteVideoTrackReceive(BaseSession baseSession, QBRTCVideoTrack qbrtcVideoTrack, Integer integer) {
        Log.i("errorCheck","inVideo 888");

        Log.i("errorCheck","inVideo 888 = "+localVideoTrack);

        mediaStreamManager = baseSession.getMediaStreamManager();
        qbrtcVideoTrack.addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(opponentView));

        localVideoTrack.removeRenderer(localVideoTrack.getRenderer());
        localVideoTrack.addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(localView));
        localView.setScalingType(RendererCommon.ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FILL);
        localView.setMirror(true);
        localView.requestLayout();
    }
```

Comment: Its because of your video screen layout . Check if you rearranging VideoView at runtime.

Comment: try this 
`localVideoView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);`